# how can i show returned result from database in same page of the submit form using php

Tags: php

**Hello, i made this simple code to show info from my database into a table, the form code is below:**
http://pastebin.com/yyzcjshn

**the show.php code is:**

```
       <html>
<head>
<title>Show Result</title>

<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if(!$connection){
die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//select database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db("sells",$connection);
if(!$db_select){
die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}


$D1 = $_POST['D1'];

//show info
if($D1 != 'Show All'){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Status='$D1'", $connection);
}
else $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients", $connection);
    if(!$result){
die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Client Name</th>
<th>URL</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price[$]</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Order_ID"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["ClientName"]."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=" . $row['Url'] . " target=_blank >" . $row['Url'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Quantity"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Price"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Status"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";



mysql_close($connection);
?>
</head>
</html>
```

**How can i show the result in the same page of the submit form using php (without ajax)?**

Comment: What is your definition of "same page"? Do you mean without refreshing the browser/navigating to a new page when the submit button is pressed?

Comment: yes, i don't want it to show the result in another page.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) and `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860046#12860046).

Comment: @user3367004 — You can't. What you are asking for is the definition of Ajax.

Comment: @Quentin i have make it with ajax: http://pastebin.com/Zrr2wVqW but i see some people use action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> to do it with php, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: @TheBlueDog i got this error when i use msqli on my local server "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in .... " any idea how can i solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't.

In the comments you say people use `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`, but that's not the same. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will echo the current scripts filename. When you use it, you don't have to write the `action` tag in your form manually.

AJAX is the method you need to update your page without refresh the whole page. You can use the (modern) AJAX method, or a redirect method. Because you don't want to use AJAX here is a redirect method example of your code:

Your `form.php`. Notice that i replaced your dropdown into a link. You can use links for a easy approuch. You can also keep your dropdown and use Javascript/JQuery to create the right redirection including the `GET` parameter:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Show Info In Table</title>
    </head>

    <body>

      ....
      <a href="/form.php?D1=Show All">Show all</a>
      ....
      <a href="/form.php?D1=Finished">Finished</a>
      ....


      <?=include('show.php');?>
    </body>

</html>
```

`show.php`, notice that `$_POST` is replaced with `$_GET`:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if(!$connection){
die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//select database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db("sells",$connection);
if(!$db_select){
die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}


$D1 = $_GET['D1'];

//show info
if($D1 != 'Show All'){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Status='$D1'", $connection);
}
else $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients", $connection);
    if(!$result){
die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Client Name</th>
<th>URL</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price[$]</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Order_ID"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["ClientName"]."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=" . $row['Url'] . " target=_blank >" . $row['Url'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Quantity"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Price"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Status"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";



mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Good luck.